# SQL Server BCP format file could not be opened. Invalid name specified or access denied

Tags: sql-server, bcp

My SQL Server table has an `Image` datatype column containing PDF's and I am trying to restore (export) them but I get stuck.

I tried different methods using BCP in SSMS but every time I export the file it is either 0 kb in size or few kb (5-10) less than the original PDF (and the file does not open). How can I restore the original pdf without being corrupted. are there any alternatives? I have 100's of files to export.

**I am able to create format file using following BCP / TSQL and also export the PDF but it is corrupted (cannot open)**

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell  'bcp TestDB.dbo.CLTDOCSX format nul -T -n -f D:\ImagesFromSql\formatfile.fmt'
```

[image: Format File]

But SQL Server throws the following errors when I run the following BCP / T-SQL

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(500)
SET @sql = 'BCP "SELECT DOCData FROM [TestDB].dbo.CLTDOCSX " QUERYOUT D:\ImagesFromSql\myfilename.pdf -T -f D:\ImagesFromSql\formatfile.fmt -S ' + @@SERVERNAME
EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql
```

[image]

I tried to run BCP command from CMD as admin but still same error.
[image]

Comment: I'm really not a fan of the method of using SQL Server to call command line to call a tool that reconnects to the SQL Server instance you are currently connected to, it's so clunky. You're better off using SQL Server's built in tools (like `BULK INSERT`) or doing this outside of SQL Server.

Comment: You have D:\ImagesFromSql\formatfile.fmt and D:\formatfile.fmt in another script, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Also `image` has been deprecated since *2005* (almost 20 years ago); you should be using it any more.

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have permission to access those files?

Comment: **@siggemannen** - I have updated the file path as per you comment and still getting same error

Comment: **@charlieface** - I have tested connection to a csv file in the same folder from SQL server using OPENROWSET, BULK INSERT methods as suggested in this post

Comment: **@ThomA** - I am trying to extract what is already in the SQL server table, can I still use BULK INSERT to extract? What other tools can I use to extract these PDF's? (data factory?)

Comment: You specify `-n` for native format when creating the format file, have you tried doing the same when using `queryout`?

Comment: **@AlwaysLearning** - yes used -n during queryout and that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolved the issue.

I found out that the data in the image column are not pdfs, they are all RAR files that can be opened using programs like 7Z or WinRAR and the actual pdfs are inside the RAR files.

I simply replaced the .pdf with .RAR in BCP query and it worked.
`QUERYOUT D:\ImagesFromSql\myfilename.rar`

All the Hex values in the image column were starting with 0x504B0304 - typically represents the file signature for a ZIP archive. So, first I tried .ZIP which did not work then .RAR which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete test script you can use:

```sql
if object_id('CLTDOCSXTest') IS NOT NULL
    drop table CLTDOCSXTest 
create table CLTDOCSXTest (DOCData Image)

-- Put file
insert into CLTDOCSXTest
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'C:\SQLServer\MSSQL11.SIGGE\MSSQL\DATA\sample.pdf',
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS DATA;

-- Create format file
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell  'bcp TestDB.dbo.CLTDOCSXTest format nul -T -n -f C:\SQLServer\MSSQL11.SIGGE\MSSQL\DATA\formatfile.fmt'

-- Export file to pdf
DECLARE @sql varchar(500)
SET @sql = 'BCP "SELECT DOCData FROM [TestDB].dbo.CLTDOCSXTest " QUERYOUT C:\SQLServer\MSSQL11.SIGGE\MSSQL\DATA\output.pdf -n -T -f C:\SQLServer\MSSQL11.SIGGE\MSSQL\DATA\formatfile.fmt -S ' + @@SERVERNAME
EXEC master.sys.xp_CmdShell @sql

-- Compare files, should return 1
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CLTDOCSXTest c
INNER JOIN OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'C:\SQLServer\MSSQL11.SIGGE\MSSQL\DATA\output.pdf',
   FORMATFILE ='C:\SQLServer\MSSQL11.SIGGE\MSSQL\DATA\formatfile.fmt') data
    ON   CAST(c.DOCData AS VARBINARY(MAX)) = CAST(data.docdata AS VARBINARY(MAX));
```

It creates a table like yours, imports a pdf, creates a bcp format file, exports the pdf and compares it to the imported one.
I have also tested with really large binary files and they work too.

Note that you need to remove the format files since i don't think they're being recreated

Comment: **[@siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13061224/siggemannen)** - your code works fine. It looks like the pdf's that I am trying to extract might have some encoding or compression applied when inserting into SQL server table. _**There is another table joining to this table which has 2 columns by the name DOCDATAX (image data type)and COMPRESS (value = XCOMPRESS)**_

Comment: Yeah then you need to decompress it the same way it's compressed. Bcp can't do that me thinks